# Qtcreator Error in Makefile in a test project

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qt-creator

I'm trying to run qtcreator for the first time.

I have create an empty Qt project with this basic code:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    return app.exec();
}
```

But when I click on "run", the Makefile give an error.

> 16:31:38: Running steps for project test...
>
> 16:31:38: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
>
> 16:31:38: Starting: "/usr/bin/make"
>
> Makefile:100: target 'all' doesn't match the target pattern
>
> Makefile:106: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
>
> 16:31:38: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
>
> Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Desktop)
>
> When executing step
>
> "Make" 16:31:38: Elapsed time: 00:00.

The line 100 is:

```
all: ../%{JS:\ Util.asciify(build-test-Desktop-Debug)}/Makefile $(TARGET)
```

and the 106 is:

```
../%{JS:\ Util.asciify(build-test-Desktop-Debug)}/Makefile: ../test/test.pro  /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/qmake.conf /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
```

Qtcreator has create an directory next to my test project named : %{JS: Util.asciify("build-test-Desktop-Debug")}

How can i solve this error?

Comment: What does your makefile look like?

Comment: It's the default makefile : https://pastebin.com/XssnpSXR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an indirect error caused by a restriction of qmake. When creating a new project, the wizard defaults to setting your build directory as `home/user/project/build`, which is not supported. Setting the build directory to `home/user/build` gets around this issue on QtCreator 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I change project/general/build directory same as the path of the project, it works in my qt Creator5.2, macOs 10.15.4